# Show and hide divs within v-for list items (Vue.js 2)

Tags: javascript, html, list, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a v-for loop and when the item within that loop is clicked I want to hide div#one and show div#two. Then click a button in div#two to hide and show div#one again. Only for that list item.

Template:

```
<div v-for="slider in slideritems">
    <div v-if="!showEdit" @click="openEditor(slider)">
        Normal list item, click to show edit options
    </div>
    <div v-if="showEdit">
        <div @click="closeEditor(slider)">Close</div>
        Edit options (if selected)
    </div>
</div>
```

Scripts:

```
export default {
    methods: {
        openEditor(slider) {
            slider.showEdit = true
        },
        closeEditor(slider) {
            slider.showEdit = false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You never defined a `closeEditor` method -- you have two `openEditor` methods.  Was that just a typo in the question?  Also, what is your actual question?  Is something not working?

Comment: Well spotted, it was an error typing it into SO, it doesn't actually fix the issue. I've updated my question slightly. I want to show and hide certain div's within a loop item. But only for that item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your methods are flipping the `showEdit` member of the slider object, I think you want `v-if` bound to `slider.showEdit`, not just `showEdit`:

```
<div v-for="slider in slideritems">
    <div v-if="!slider.showEdit" @click="openEditor(slider)">
        Normal list item, click to show edit options
    </div>
    <div v-if="slider.showEdit">
        <div @click="closeEditor(slider)">Close</div>
        Edit options (if selected)
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's a working jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/psteele/wn1npgqu/

Answer (score 2):

```
<li v-for="(data, index) in skills" :key="index+1">
  {{index + 1}}. {{data.skillName}}
  <i v-b-toggle="index + 1" class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>             
  <b-collapse v-bind:id="index + 1" class="mt-2">Here will be your result</b- 
 collapse>
</li>
```

You can get an idea from **bootstrap-vue.js**. I solve my purpose with that.
Here is the link https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/collapse/